# Fluent Nhibernate table with value object mapping

Tags: .net, oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Can you suggest a valid mapping for the following scenario. Two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "ORDER"
  (
    "ID"      NUMBER(20,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "STATUS_ID"  NVARCHAR2(10,0)
  );

CREATE TABLE "STATUS"
  (
    "ID"      NVARCHAR2(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "DESCRIPTION"  NVARCHAR2(250,0)
  );
```

The respective classes are:

```
public class Order
{
    public virtual Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Status { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public virtual Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Description { get; set; }
}
```

Status table is static table of value object for the property `Proposal.Status` and should never be manipulated by code. I want the `Order` to always be loaded with Status description and code, i.e. Eager Load `Proposal.Status`.

I've read this [Ayende's blog post](http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/23/a-fluent-interface-to-nhibernate-part-2-value-objects) but there is no exactly the same scenario, albeit I believe it's quite common.

Edit: note I'm trying to do this as `Component Map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to map a regular entity with identity as a component (value object). From Ayende's post:

> In DDD you have the notion of entities and value objects. **The latter
>   are immutable and have no identity**. In NHibernate they are **mapped as
>   Component and its fields are embedded in the same table as the
>   containing entity**.

Component mapping should be used when you are mapping a value type to the same table as the parent entity. You can find more information about NHibernate types in [documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-types).

Try instead to do it using References mapping, although you might be tempted to [use HasOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382943/hasone-vs-references-mapping-fluent-nhibernate).

Comment: Funny enough, I've started with `HasOne` before I realised it wasn't appropriate. I did think that Status is a Value Object, but yes it will have a natural Id field (`StatusCode`), so I guess it isn't. `References` does the job allright.